# Azure Websites - Increase Java / Tomcat heap size?

Tags: java, tomcat, azure

I have been trying to increase the heap size within my Azure website instance without any luck.. I have built a web.config file per some recommendations and put it in the /site/wwwroot folder but it doesn't seem to be overriding the default. For reference, my web.config looks like;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="httppPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>

    <httpPlatform processPath="%programfiles(x86)%\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\bin\startup.bat">
        <environmentVariables>
            <environmentVariable name="CATALINA_HOME" value="%programfiles(x86)%\apache-tomcat-7.0.50"/>
            <environmentVariable name="JAVA_OPTS" value="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xms128m -Xmx512m"/>
            <environmentVariable name="CATALINA_OPTS" value="-Dport.http=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%"/>
        </environmentVariables>
    </httpPlatform>
</system.webServer>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated by both myself and I'm sure others who are trying to do the same thing as well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

My preferred way (Removes dependency on specific minor version of Tomcat 7):

```
processPath="%AZURE_TOMCAT7_HOME%\bin\startup.bat"
```

---

The other way (here `programfiles` points to the `Program Files (x86)` folder:

```
processPath="%programfiles%\apache-tomcat-7.0.50\bin\startup.bat"
```

Comment: This didn't help. Below is the content of my web.config file and it gave ERROR 500. `
    <httpPlatform processPath="%AZURE_TOMCAT85_HOME%\bin\startup.bat">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="CATALINA_OPTS" value="-Dport.http=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" />
        <environmentVariable name="CATALINA_HOME" value="%AZURE_TOMCAT85_HOME%" />
        <environmentVariable name="JAVA_OPTS" value="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xmx256m -Xmx512m -Xms1g"/>
      </environmentVariables>
    </httpPlatform>`

Answer (score 0):

Remove those settings in “JAVA_OPTS” and add them into “CATALINA_OPTS” as below, because java heap size should go under CATALINA_OPTS:

```
<httpPlatform processPath="%AZURE_TOMCAT85_HOME%\bin\startup.bat">
    <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="CATALINA_OPTS" value="-Dport.http=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -Xms512m -Xmx2048m" />
        <environmentVariable name="CATALINA_HOME" value="%AZURE_TOMCAT85_HOME%" />
    </environmentVariables>
</httpPlatform>
```

Answer (score 0):

Abdenaceur's solution above is the "Microsoft" answer however it did not work for us.  Instead of this:

```
<environmentVariable name="CATALINA_OPTS" value="-Dport.http=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -Xms512m -Xmx2048m" />
```

what worked for us was this:

```
<httpPlatform processPath="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" arguments="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dspring.profiles.active=%spring.profiles.active% -Dserver.port=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -jar &quot;%HOME%\site\wwwroot\BLA-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar&quot;">
      </httpPlatform>
```

So the complete file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
         <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <httpPlatform processPath="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" arguments="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dspring.profiles.active=%spring.profiles.active% -Dserver.port=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -jar &quot;%HOME%\site\wwwroot\BLAA_Api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar&quot;">
      </httpPlatform>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for us is adding the `CATALINA_OPTS` at "Application settings" in the section "Application settings".

E.g. set it to `-Xmx20m` and reboot your application and you will likely get an OutOfMemory Error instantly because 20MB is not enough.
If that worked you can obviously adjust -Xmx to your needs and reboot again.